# How to remove white space at bottom of blogger page?

Tags: blogger, removing-whitespace

I really can't figure out how to get rid of a large chunk of white space under my main body of text and sidebar.

I've tried changing padding and margins linked with footers to 1px but nothing works. http://ellenaraetester.blogspot.co.uk/ anyone know?

Comment: If its not the footer could you post the print screen

Answer (score 0):

This is a **footer**. You can add css:

```
  .footer-outer {display:none;}
```

Comment: after adding this footer removal it just deleted the nice gap of visible background at the bottom which separated the main body from the bottom of the screen. i played around a bit and just added a code to make the main body heigh a bit shorter and seems to have decreased the white space to a reasonable depth. thanks for your help though